# BreezeJS MergeStrategy error

Tags: breeze, single-page-application

I have the following two models:

```
 public class ModelA {
      public IList<ModelB> list { get; set; }
      // rest properties
 }

 public class ModelB {
     public ModelA navProp { get; set; }
     // rest properties
 }
```

When my application loads, I fetch all the data; that is, instances of ModelA include all the values of the collection navigation property list. 
In other words, I don't apply the *eager loading* or *loading on demand* techniques to fetch the data for the navigation property.

The problem with that is that I get the following error:

```
A MergeStrategy of 'Disallowed' does not allow you to attach an entity when an entity with the same key is already attached:
```

Looking at the code, I noticed that the first instance of ModelA is attached twice. It seems that breeze tries to recursively attach the entities into the cache (starting from the navigation property).

I just wonder if I'm following the wrong path. I have the impression that breeze expects us to explicitly load the related entities.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't creating entities with the same Id using something like manager.createEntity()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bug that caused this error message was fixed in breeze 1.5.2.